# Dell Latitude E6420 does not detect Dell External monitor P221 2H

Tags: display, troubleshooting, vga, external-display, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude E6420 and recently got a Dell Monitor P221 2H.
The issue is that the Laptop is not detecting the external monitor and Monitor is displaying "Entering Power save mode".

I tried connecting it through the VGA cable that came with the monitor and also tried with a DVI-D cable to connect but no success.

I tried going to control panel->Display and tried the option to detect and identify but nothing on the monitor.

The display adapter shows Standard VGA Graphic Adapter if it helps.

What i am missing and how can i get my external monitor working with my laptop.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT::**

--> I tried using both docking station(DVI-D) and connecting directly to laptop(VGA port in this case).

--> Pressing Fn + f8 did not help(nothing happened in this case).

--> I have latest display drivers.

--> Laptop has BIOS version A08 (did not updated this as this is the latest for my laptop)

--> Using Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: You need to provide more details. [Edit] your question to include the following. Is this in a docking station or just connected directly to the laptop? Have you tried `Fn` + `F8` to cycle through the displays? Have you updated the BIOS? Have you made sure you have the latest display drivers? What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you verified this monitor work connected to another computer? Does any other monitor work with your laptop?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes the Monitor works with other laptop. I don't have any other monitor check the second point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by updating the drivers for on board graphic card.